# SSRS Report Access to others

Tags: reporting-services

I've developed an SSRS 2008 report on my PC with IIS 7.0. Currently, I'm able to access the reports. How do I provide permissions to others to be able to see the reports by going through my local host?

Comment: When they are accessing your localhost, what is the url they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure permissions in the Report Manager.   By default: http://localhost/ReportManager

Or Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager

You can then directly link your users to your machine or configure IIS to point to a custom report page.

Comment: When I try adding a USER for System Role Assignment, it gives me the following error

The user or group name 'Domain\Username' is not recognized

Comment: @user1345260 make sure the DOMAIN and username are valid.  Try adding a SQL Server role and see if that makes a difference

Comment: The user you are trying to add needs to be a user in Domain\Username. Like localhost\user1. A valid user on the domain of the ReportManager. In this case, localhost

Answer (score 1):

you should be able if you are on a domain group. Maybe the other users dont have access to your computer (seems to be a local instance of SSRS).

Also you could try (just for testing, of course) adding "Everyone" and give permissions to see if they can access.